# .has() function not working in if statement (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have this code:

```
if ($('.workflow-item:eq(0)').has(".tube-wrapper")) {
  itemresT = 0;
  console.log('0 has tube')
} else if ($('.workflow-item').eq(1).has(".tube-wrapper")) {
  itemResT = 1;
  console.log('1 has tube')
} else if ($('.workflow-item').eq(2).has(".tube-wrapper")) {
  itemResT = 2;
  console.log('2 has tube')
} else if ($('.workflow-item').eq(3).has(".tube-wrapper")) {
  itemResT = 3;
  console.log('3 has tube')
} else {}
```

It's quite easy, it checks the four `.workflow-item` if they contain the element `.tube-wrapper`.

In my case, `.workflow-item` number 3 contains the `.tube-wrapper`, so it should return '2 has tube'. But, it returns '0 has tube' everytime. Even when I put the `.tube-wrapper` in `.workflow-item number 4`.

Comment: it will be always true since defined variable accepted as truthy value, you can use `$('.workflow-item').eq(1).has(".tube-wrapper").length`

Comment: Ah nice! It worked! Thank you very much! You might want to add a comment, so I can check it as 'solved' ;)

Comment: glad to help you :) !!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If conditions will be always true, since **[`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/)** returns jQuery object and it will be always true since defined variable accepted as truth value. You can use **[`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/)** property of it or **[`size()`](https://api.jquery.com/size/)** method.

```
if($('.workflow-item').eq(1).has(".tube-wrapper").length)
```

---

Or you can use **[`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/)** with **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** selector

```
if($('.workflow-item').eq(1).is(':has(.tube-wrapper)'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the .hasClass() to get a boolean value

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

```
if($('.workflow-item').eq(1).hasClass(".tube-wrapper"))
```

Comment: Yeah, but I am searching for an element inside the .workflow-item div.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't figure what you are asking, from your last comment, I guess you need a `.find()` can you please post a piece of HTML to clarify what you need ? Thanks!

Comment: Well, to be honest, the comment above did just the trick :p Your way might work, but he was just a bit earlier :/ But still, you can have my upvote, because I know what your mean!

Comment: awesome! :) Thank you very much